# Could Proto-Slavic -ъ be from *-ós

Tags: proto-indo-european, slavic-languages, lithuanian

Lithuanian has -as from PIE *-os draug**as** and -us from PIE *-ós draug**us**, Proto-Slavic has only -ъ. Could Proto-Slavic -ъ be from *-ós with analogical restitution?
Lithuanian has -ias from PIE *yos and -ys from PIE *-yós, Proto-Slavic has only jь. Could Proto-Slavic -jь be from *-yós with analogical restitution?

Comment: why would you need analogy here?

Comment: @Tristan Can you explain the transformation from 2 variants to 1 somehow else?

Comment: mergers happen all the time without analogy